# How to send One Time Password using Twilio in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, twilio, twilio-php, twilio-click-to-call

I need your help to create One Time Password (OTP) using Twilio in JavaScript to generate OTP and verify it using JavaScript.

I have surfed about this in Twilio. They have given Two Factor Authentication to send OTP in PHP, Ruby, C#, Python and Java, but not for JavaScript.

Any one please help me to achieve this Two Factor Authentication using JavaScript.

Comment: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2012/04/two-factor-authentication-with-node-js-and-twilio.html

Comment: How can i create voice url in twiml app???

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

JBux commented with a great [link to a blog post](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2012/04/two-factor-authentication-with-node-js-and-twilio.html) that should help, though be aware that some things might be out of date as that post is from 2012.

I'd like to add another suggestion. [Authy](https://www.authy.com/) became a part of the Twilio family earlier this year with a service that makes setting up Two Factor Authentication really easy. There is a great, and up to date, tutorial on [implementing Two Factor Authentication in Node.js using Authy](https://www.twilio.com/docs/howto/walkthrough/two-factor-authentication/node/express) on the Twilio site.

Let me know if that helps at all.